# omp.h header file not found in SUSE linux

Tags: c, openmp, header-files, suse

I wanted to execute a simple OPENMP Program in Suse linux and when I compile it with commmand "**gcc -openmp example.c -O example**" it gives an error "**omp.h header not found**" . How can include this header file so that i can execute this .

Answer (score 3):

> when I compile it with commmand "gcc -openmp example.c -O example"

You error is that the flag that enables OpenMP handling in GCC is `-fopenmp` and not `-openmp`. With `-fopenmp` the path to `omp.h` is added automatically to the list of include paths.

As to where the actual `omp.h` file is located - it is usually located together with the other support files in the library folder. On RedHat-based distros it is in `/usr/lib/gcc/<arch>-redhat-linux/<version>/include/omp.h` where `<arch>` is the architecture (e.g. `x86_64`) and `<version>` is the GCC version (e.g. `4.4.4`). Other distros may choose a different place.

One more thing - the option to specify the output executable is `-o` (small letter `O`). `-O` (capital letter `O`) enables some basic optimisations on the compiled code.

Comment: No even that doesnt work . It gives an error "unrecognized commad line option "-fopenmp" .

Comment: @Deepesh.Shetty, could you please paste here the command line as you type it as well as the output from `gcc -v`?

Comment: "ivml2005:~/openmp # gcc hello.c -openmp
hello.c:12:17: error: omp.h: No such file or directory"

Comment: Now paste the output with `-fopenmp` and the output from `gcc -v` please.

Comment: ivml2005:~/openmp # gcc -fopenmp hello.c
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-fopenmp"

Comment: ivml2005:~/openmp # gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
Target: i586-suse-linux
gcc version 4.1.2 20070115 (prerelease) (SUSE Linux)

Comment: @Deepesh.Shetty, GCC 4.1 does not support OpenMP. You should install GCC 4.2 or higher for OpenMP support - see the [GCC Wiki](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/openmp).